# holomorphic function on the upper plane

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence of distinct real numbers. Show that there exists a function $f$  holomorphic on the upper half plane such that $f(i+x_n)=0$ for all $n$ if and only if
$$
\sum_n\frac1{x_n^2+4}<\infty
$$

$ $

My attempt: consider the transformation $\phi(z)=\frac{z-i}{z+i}$ which maps the upper half plane onto unit disk $\mathbb D$. Then I have no idea.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: is the $4$ in the sum?

Comment: @ellya, oh yes. I edited the post.

Comment: @ellya,can you give me some hints?

Answer (score 1):

This follows from the Blaschke condition on upper half-plane (for example, see [Levin, B. Ya. Lectures on entire functions. In collaboration with and with a preface by Yu. Lyubarskii, M. Sodin and V. Tkachenko. Translated from the Russian manuscript by Tkachenko. Translations of Mathematical Monographs, 150. American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 1996. xvi+248 pp. ISBN: 0-8218-0282-8 MR1400006 (97j:30001) , p. 99](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u8pzht6td5ars7y/Blaschke%20condition.docx) ).